# Array of checkbox values in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, checkbox

I have a HTML form with multiple checkbox selection. They are defined as:

```
<label class="container">Afghanistan
        <input type="checkbox" id="Afghanistan" name="country[]" value="Afghanistan" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container">Armenia
        <input type="checkbox" id="Armenia" name="country[]" value="Armenia" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
...
```

After submitting, I call a PHP file where I want to store their values in an array.

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_POST["country[]"]);$i++){
    $country[i] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["country[i]"]);
  }
```

But this code doesn't work. Can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: Is this html wrapped in a form with `method="post"`?

Comment: Yes:
<form id="form_id" action="http://localhost/food_values.php" method="post" name="myform">

It reads the checkboxvalues but I don't know how to manage the multiple options instead of only one

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST["country"]` is an array for which you can get the values using the index using `$i`

Try it like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_POST["country"]);$i++){
        $country[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["country"][$i]);
    }
    echo $country[0];
}
```

Comment: it should be $country[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["country"][$i]); echo $country[$i];

Comment: @xam That is correct, I have updated my answer. If you want your values in an array you could add them like `$country[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["country"][$i]);` and retrieve them for example like `$country[0]`